# Paraphrasing as they are mediated by the storage of media which are retrieved at indeterminate and undirected times by the eventual audience

Tags: sentence-structure, paraphrasing

I am not just just stuck audience issue I cant understand what the author tries to say with "as they are mediated by the storage of media which are retrieved at indeterminate and undirected times by the eventual audience"

Other categories of Internet datacast, such as a simple broadcast email, webcasting or bulletin board posting, are asynchronous **as they are mediated by the storage of media which are retrieved at indeterminate and undirected times by the eventual audience**. Nor do social expectations about Internet datacasting conform to any kind of appointed
regulation, unlike broadcast events.

Source: Communication Theory; Media, Technology and Society belonging to David Holmes

Comment: Looks as though the author is trying to define "asynchronous". The consumer of an asynchronous datacast retrieves the datacast file from storage on an ad hoc basis, at a time that suits the consumer.  That process of storing and retrieving the file the author is calling "mediation".  The aspirin is in aisle 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make sense of this, it is necessary to understand what synchronous media are. See http://www.asaecenter.org/Resources/articledetail.cfm?itemnumber=13572 for a better discussion.

Synchronous media are marked by simultaneous generation and comprehension of information. An example is a conference call. You speak, and everybody else hears.

Asynchronous media, such as the examples given, are recorded and then viewed or heard by different people (the audience) at different times. This forum is an example.

So the phrase you're having trouble with might be paraphrased as "since they store the information (rather than immediately broadcasting it), and the information is retrieved at completely unpredictable intervals by the people who make up the audience"

Comment: I am really grateful for all of your efforts on this. All really worked out for me especially WhatRoughBeast's

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think what you need is to simplify phrases.

As we can see 
-mediated means intervene or go between. We can choose a esay one that is go between. Incidentally, intervene is a vi. word.

-the storage of media do not need to change because if any phrase has the, that means this is a specific term.

-retrieved means derived, the most common collocation for this word is derived from.

-indeterminate means vague. And undirected means uncertain.
Therefore, you can change the sentence sturcture and make an excellent paraphasing.

-they go between the storage of media which derived from the eventual audience's vague and uncertain times.